# Coupon Magento API Soap

Tags: web-service, magento, soap

Eu tenho um problema com a API Cupom do Magento quando eu faço:

```
$couponCode = "test";

$resultCartCoupon = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_coupon.add", array($shoppingCartId, $couponCode));
```

Eu sempre tenho:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1083] Coupon is not valid

Se eu tentar o código do cupom no *front-end*, não há problema.
Existe alguém que já usou essa parte da API com o sucesso?